# jQuery + JSON - How can I select classes based on corresponding JSON strings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json

I'm going to post the codepen here in case anyone wants to see the whole thing in context: http://codepen.io/JTBennett/pen/NdLWJy

And now I'll try to distill the issue. I have a click event that selects from a JSON object based on one of its string values. Various strings are brought into divs as text, but I'm trying to make some divs that are hidden fade in if a group of strings in the JSON object contains a particular value (I made it easy by using the same class names in the string values).

Here's an example of one of the JSON objects:

```
{
"CSS":"A_Aeolian",
"root":"A",
"scale":"Aeolian",
"name":"A Aeolian",
"type":"Scale",
"structure":"A B C D E F G",
"noteClass_1":"A",
"noteClass_2":"B",
"noteClass_3":"C",
"noteClass_4":"D",
"noteClass_5":"E",
"noteClass_6":"F",
"noteClass_7":"G",
"noteClass_8":""
}
```

And here's my jQuery:

```
$('.A, .As, .B, .C, .Cs, .D, .Ds, .E, .F, .Fs, .G, .Gs').hide();

$.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/non2t.json", function(data) {
  $('.main-btn').on("click", function () {
    $('#total-scale-men').empty()
    console.log("emptied total-scale-men");
    $('.gcMen ul li button').css({'border' : '1px #666 solid',
   'color' : '#666'})
    $('.scales-men').hide()
    $('.scales-men').fadeIn()
    $(this).css({'border' : '1px #cc4c4c solid',
   'color' : '#cc4c4c'})
        var scale = $(this).data('scale')
        $.each(data,function(i,data){
            if (scale == data.root) {
                $('#total-scale-men').append('<button class="scale-btn" data-css="'+ data.CSS +'">' + data.scale + '</button>');
            }
        });

        $('.scale-btn').on("click", function () {
    $('.nt').hide()
    $('.scales-men').hide()
    $('.gcMen ul li button').css({'border' : '1px #666 solid','color' : '#666'})

      var css = $(this).data('css')
      $.each(data,function(i,data){
        var notes = [data.noteClass_1,
                     data.noteClass_2,
                     data.noteClass_3,
                     data.noteClass_4,
                     data.noteClass_5,
                     data.noteClass_6,
                     data.noteClass_7,
                     data.noteClass_8]
        var ntClass = ['.A','.As','.B','.C','.Cs','.D','.Ds','.E','.F','.Fs','.G','.Gs']
      if (css == data.CSS) {
        $('#inf div:nth-child(1)').text(data.root)
        $('#inf div:nth-child(2)').text(data.scale)
        $('#inf div:nth-child(3)').text(data.structure)
        if (notes[0] == 'A') {
          $(ntClass[0]).fadeIn()
        }
      }
      });
  })

    })
});
```

You can see that I put the noteClass string values and div class values into arrays - and I can select corresponding string/class values to fade in divs by selecting manually with the if statement:

```
        if (notes[0] == 'A') {
          $(ntClass[0]).fadeIn()
        }
```

How can I make it so all the values of the two arrays (notes & ntClass) are compared and then whenever there's a match, that class will fade in?

I hope my intentions are clear enough, if not then maybe looking at the codepen will help (http://codepen.io/JTBennett/pen/NdLWJy)

Any help here would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if I've misunderstood your question, but I think that you want to do this:

```
$("." + notes[0]).fadeIn();
```

Since the only difference between your notes and your classes is the class dot preceding them, this should work.

Comment: That's definitely a smarter approach than mine ^_^. But unfortunately, I'm still trying to adapt it because it doesn't seem to work - i tried this with no luck: for(var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++)
        $("." + notes[i]).fadeIn();